# DataGrid Highchart: Render image inside column

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datagrid

How to render an image inside datagrid Highchart?

Currently my datagrid is working fine, but there's one column (Status) which require to render the value inside that particular column instead of displaying the url.

Tried to read all the API documentation but i dont think I can find any solution.
I have also referred to these but still couldnt find an answer.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/dashboards/datagrid-component
https://api.highcharts.com/dashboards/#interfaces/DataGrid_DataGridOptions.ColumnOptions

Below is my code:

```
    Dashboards.board('TaskGrid', {
            
            dataPool: {
                connectors: [{
                    id: 'taskdata',
                    type: 'JSON',
                    options: {
                        firstRowAsNames: false,
                        columnNames: ['Main Tasks', 'No.', 'Task', 'Start Date', 'Finish Date', 'Percent Complete', 'Status', 'Status0'],
                        data: taskJSONData
                    }
                }]
            },
            gui: {
                layouts: [{
                    id: 'layout-1',
                    rows: [{
                        cells: [{
                            id: 'taskdata-col'
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            },
            components: [{
                cell: 'taskdata-col',
                connector: {
                    id: 'taskdata'
                },
                type: 'DataGrid',
                dataGridOptions: {
                    editable: false,
                    columns: {
                        Status: {
                            cellFormat: '{value}',
                            // (<img src="{value}" alt="image" />)',
                            //cellFormat: '<img src="{value}" alt="image" />',
                            //template: '<img src="{value}" alt="image" />',
                            headerFormat: '{text}',
                        },
                    }
                }
            }]
            
        });
```

Edit: Or is there an alternative to render the imageurl inside the datagrid?

Comment: Unfortunately because of sanitation, it isn't possible right now. I've added this as a request: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20634

I haven't found any easy workaround for now.